# Infinite loop FutureBuilder when use Provider

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider, flutter-futurebuilder

I have method like this in my provider file to get a list of items :

```
Future<void> getServerMeals() async {
    final QueryBuilder<ParseObject> parseQuery =
        QueryBuilder<ParseObject>(ParseObject('UsersEaten'));

    final ParseResponse apiResponse = await parseQuery.query();

    if (apiResponse.success && apiResponse.results != null) {
      List<dynamic>? apiRes = apiResponse.results;
      List<EatenItem> newMeals = apiRes!
          .map((e) => EatenItem(
                id: e['objectId'],
                eatenCal: e['eatenCal'],
                eatenTitle: e['eatenTitle'],
                eatenImageUrl: e['eatenImg'],
                userId: e['objectId'],
              ))
          .toList();
      _eatenMeals = newMeals;
      print(apiResponse.results);
      notifyListeners();
    }
  }
```

and in my main screen I have a StatelessWidget and FutureBuilder to get that list :

```
class TimelineWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [

        Container(
          child: FutureBuilder(
           future: Provider.of<EatenMeals>(context, listen: false).getServerMeals(),
            builder: (ctx, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                return Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                );
              }

              return Consumer<EatenMeals>(
                builder: (ctx, mealsList, child) => ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: mealsList.eatenMeals.length,
                  itemBuilder: (ctx, index) =>
                      DailyEaten(mealsList.eatenMeals[index]),
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

as you can see there is nothing in my build method and I've tried to use Consumer as future to avoid infinite loop but it doesn't work for me please tell me what's wrong here I appreciate if u explain with code snippet

Comment: if you want to change the state of your widget, why you have used the `Stateless widget`?

Comment: I have same issue with statefulwidget

Comment: If you want to use the FeatureBuilder then don't use a Consumer and don't use a notifyListeners. The entire point of the FB is to only be used once and that's it... but you're forcing the change notifier to update and having a consumer listening for changes as well

Comment: @MarianoZorrilla so how do I rebuild my list when changes occurred in `getServerMeals()` for example if user select specific date I want to rebuild my list inside of FutureBuilder without `notifylistener `how do I do that

Comment: You'll need to actually return a value instead of "void" if you want to continue using FutureBuilder. If you're going the path of full Provider, then... is not the best logic as this problem will happen every time.